# What is invalid next in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iterator, enumerable

The following code works:

```
collection.each do |i|
  begin
    next if i > 10
    i += 1
  rescue
    puts "could not process #{ i }"
  end
end
```

However, when we refactor:

```
collection.each do |i|
  begin
    increment i
  rescue
    puts "could not process #{ i }"
  end
end

def increment i
  next if i > 10
  i += 1
end
```

I get `invalid next` error. Is this a limitation of Ruby (1.9.3)?

Does the `begin rescue` block work the same way if there is an exception in the increment method?

Comment: My question is what does he expect `next` to do?

Comment: Yes, this is a simplified example. If I posted production code it would obscure the question.

Comment: It's not a "limitation", it's a design decision, and a *good* one. You *shouldn't* be able to move the `next` out of the context of the loop. You can't in any other language either.

Comment: Outside of the fact that you are attempting to alter the flow of a loop from a method call, the scope of `i` within the method `increment` is local to that method. So it becomes a different `i` than the one in your loop. Not only does the `next` not work that way, the increment of `i` won't work that way either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `next` statement must occur inside a loop. There's no loop inside your `increment` method.

Exceptions will 'bubble up', so if there's an exception in your `increment` method, it will be caught by the `rescue` section of the calling method.